# Question on homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $K=[0,1]^n$. Let $L\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a set homeomorphic with $K$. Choose $a$ in the interior of $K$, $b$ on the boundary of $L$. Then can $K\setminus \{a\}$ and $L\setminus \{b\}$ be homeomorphic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. First note that a homeomorphism from $K$ to $L$ takes interior
points to interior points (and so does its inverse). This follows from
Brouwer's Invariance of Domain Theorem. So we may assume $K=L$. Removing
a boundary point from $K$ gives a contractible set, which removing an interior point gives a space with nonzero $H_{n-1}$.